# C linked list circular reference

Tags: c, linked-list, circular-reference

So I'm pretty new to C, but not to programming. I am trying to learn C and so I decided to try implementing a simple linked list.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct node node;
struct node {
    char *word;
    node *next;
};

// Returns a node.
node node_new(char *word) {
    node n;
    n.word = word;
    n.next = NULL;
    return n;
}

// Traverses the linked list, spitting out the
// words onto the console.
void traverse(node *head) {
    node *cur = head;

    while (cur != NULL) {
        printf("I have %s.\n", cur->word);
        cur = cur->next;
    }

    printf("Done.\n");

    return;
}

// In here I get circular references whenever I pass a second argument.
void dynamic(int argc, char **argv) {
    printf("DYNAMIC:\n");

    node n = node_new("ROOT");
    node *cur = &n;

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        node next = node_new(argv[i]);
        cur->next = &next;
        cur = &next;
    }

    traverse(&n);
}

void predefined(void) {
    printf("PREDEFINED:\n");

    node n = node_new("ROOT");
    node a = node_new("A");
    node b = node_new("B");
    node c = node_new("C");

    n.next = &a;
    a.next = &b;
    b.next = &c;

    traverse(&n);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    predefined();
    dynamic(argc, argv);
    return 0;
}
```

If I just run it without arguments ("./test") the output is:

```
PREDEFINED:
I have ROOT.
I have A.
I have B.
I have C.
Done.
DYNAMIC:
I have ROOT.
I have ./test.
Done.
```

but if I put any arguments on, instead of "I have ./test." it gives an infinite loop of whatever the last argument on the command line was ("./test one two three" gives "i have three." over and over ignores the "one" and "two", but the preceding lines are the same).

I think it has to do with bad pointer management in the dynamic function, but I can't figure out why it's setting itself to its own "next" node.

Comment: i think you have a stack allocation vs heap problem?

Comment: when you allocate on the stack, and make the copy node n = new_node(), it releases n at the end of the scope (your for loop)

Comment: It does release n, which is exactly what I want. The first time through the for loop, it sets the "head"'s next node to point to n. I can't think what I'm doing wrong.

And I can't see why I'd need malloc since I'm not doing any dynamic memory management. I'm only moving pointers. But I have never used C before two days ago so I really don't know.

Comment: you've exactly hit the point but in the wrong way - you aren't using dynamic mm. That means whatever you did to n, created, edited, etc is undone at the } at the end of the for loop. its scope is local and a new "n" is created in the exact same spot in the next loop iteration

Comment: read @wallyk's answer which explains it clearly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
for (i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
    node next = node_new(argv[i]);
    cur->next = &next;
    cur = &next;
}
```

By allocating `next` like this, it remains tied to the stack and doesn't actually change address on each iteration.  It should be a new object each time:

```
for (i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
    node *next = malloc (sizeof node);
    next->word = argv[i];
    next->next = NULL;
    cur->next = next;
    cur = next;
}
```

Also, `node_new()` can't be used because it doesn't allocate any lasting new memory either.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your `for` loop. Every iteration uses the same memory location on the stack to store the `next` variable. So, effectively, the memory location given by `&next` is a constant for your entire `for` loop, and by the time you run `traverse`, that memory location contains last value of `next`.

Your `for` loop is equivalent to this version, which might shed more light:

```
int i;
node next;  // note this line
for (i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
    next = node_new(argv[i]);
    cur->next = &next;
    cur = &next;
}
```

You'll need to create new nodes on the heap, if you want to be able to pass their addresses around, or store their addresses in other data structures. Read up on `malloc` and `free`.